# C# SqlCommand command with parameter in the middle of query

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameters

I'm having an issue with inserting parameter through a SQLCommand in C#.
When parameter **legal_GUID** was in the end of query it works well.

```
string[] param = getHTTPparams(connection);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT AD.document_GUID ,AT.attachment_fileName ,do
                          FROM [legal].[mdm].[View_All_Documents] AD
                          LEFT JOIN [legal].[dbo].[AllAttachments] AT
                          ON AD.document_GUID = AT.document_GUID
                          WHERE AD.legal_GUID = '" + legal_GUID + "'", connection);
```

But when i am trying to make changes to query and current parameter **legal_GUID** moves to the middle of the query it doesn't work.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"DECLARE @order_guid_tr uniqueidentifier
                               SELECT 1 @order_guid_tr = Order_guid
                               FROM [legal].[mdm].[View_All_Documents]
                               WHERE legal_GUID = '" + legal_GUID + "'
                               SELECT AD.document_GUID ,AT.attachment_fileName, document_type
                           FROM [legal].[mdm].[View_All_Documents] AD
                           LEFT JOIN [legal].[dbo].[AllAttachments] AT
                           ON AD.document_GUID = AT.document_GUID
                           WHERE AD.ORDER_GUID = @order_guid_tr", connection);
```

What changes do I need to make to the query syntax, what do I miss?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: "Doesn't work" *how*?  What fails?  It looks like you're trying to run multiple queries as one.  Why?  Also, why aren't you using query parameters?

Comment: The `1` in `SELECT 1 @order_guid_tr = Order_guid...` doesn't look right.

Comment: I think you should put a semicolon between the two statements. Not sure if that fixes the issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do inline sql like that you have to let the parser know that it's a new statement.  You can either do that with a space, carriage return or semi colon.  Also you're missing the keyword top to get the first record from View_All_Documents

If you change to be:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"DECLARE @order_guid_tr uniqueidentifier;
                               SELECT top 1 @order_guid_tr = Order_guid
                               FROM [legal].[mdm].[View_All_Documents]
                               WHERE legal_GUID = '" + legal_GUID + "';
                               SELECT AD.document_GUID ,AT.attachment_fileName, document_type
                           FROM [legal].[mdm].[View_All_Documents] AD
                           LEFT JOIN [legal].[dbo].[AllAttachments] AT
                           ON AD.document_GUID = AT.document_GUID
                           WHERE AD.ORDER_GUID = @order_guid_tr", connection);
```

It should work but this is very **bad** to do.  By doing this you allow for a [sql injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) attack against your code.

Comment: A semicolon isn't required here. The actual issue looks to be the missing `top` which you've added (though not mentioned).

Comment: In the OP there is no space so there needs to be a delimiter for the parser.  I have updated answer to include keyword top

Comment: Yes there are - It's a verbatim string so the text will include all the newlines as seen in the code (as well as all the spaces used to indent the lines from the 2nd onwards).

Answer (score 2):

As Avitus already mentioned it is unsafe to put parameters into the query by concatenating strings.
You should better use the Parameters of the SqlCommand for that:

```
        string sql = "SELECT AD.document_GUID, AT.attachment_fileName, document_type
                      FROM [legal].[mdm].[View_All_Documents] AD LEFT JOIN [legal].[dbo].[AllAttachments] AT
                      ON AD.document_GUID = AT.document_GUID
                      WHERE AD.ORDER_GUID IN (SELECT TOP 1 Order_guid FROM [legal].[mdm].[View_All_Documents] WHERE legal_GUID = @legal_GUID)";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@legal_GUID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).SqlValue = legal_GUID;
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll probably want to use CommandText to define the query and Parameters property to bind the expected filter to the query.
I believe this example can be useful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2